# How to store values in a pyramid session?

Tags: session, pyramid

Let's assume that I use the default pyramid `UnencryptedCookieSessionFactory`

```
...
my_session_factory = UnencryptedCookieSessionFactoryConfig('itsaseekreet')
config = Configurator(settings=settings)
config.set_session_factory(my_session_factory)
...
```

and define two views with a link to each other:

```
@view_config(route_name='t1')
def t1(request):
    session = request.session
    session['fred'] = '***'
    session['abc'] = '&&&'
    return Response(str(session.__dict__) + '<a href="t2">t2</a>')

@view_config(route_name='t2')
def t2(request):
    session = request.session
    return Response(str(session.__dict__) + '<a href="t1">t1</a>')
```

If I visit t1 in browser I get the following output:

```
{'accessed': 1377760577, '_dirty': True, 'request': , 'new': False, 'created': 1377760540.30155}t2
```

and if i follow the link to t2:

```
{'accessed': 1377760577, 'request': , 'new': False, 'created': 1377760540.30155}t1
```

But I would expect something different for t1 and t2:

```
{ ..., 'fred': '***', 'abc': '&&&', ...}
```

Why are the values not stored in the session? And what does the _dirty flag mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session.__dict__` is not the api for dealing with sessions. The session underneath is implemented as a `dict` object which does not use `__dict__` to store its contents. You're simply printing out the attributes on the class which are unrelated. Print out something like `session.items()` instead or just `session` since its a `dict`.